# Can I receive emergency alerts on an IPad through WiFi?

Tags: ios, ipad, notifications, settings

I have an iPad Pro with iOS 12.1.1, WiFi only (it has a cell modem but I never activated it), in USA. Can I enable wireless emergency alerts somehow? Like the NWS and AMBER alerts I get on my phone.

All internet instructions ([example](https://alvinalexander.com/apple/how-to-disable-amber-alerts-ios-devices-iphone-ipad)) refer to a "government alerts" section at the bottom of Notification settings, but I don't have that, there's nothing below the app list on that page.

Comment: I know that there are extensions within the 802.11 specs that provides for delivering "emergency messages" like weather but maybe it's not supported on a wi-fi only iPad? FCC doesn't mandate that all Wi-Fi networks/devices be able to send and receive EAS messages like it does for phones, and I'm not sure how many stations there are that implement this feature in the U.S. I haven't seen any yet at least.